# GNU Backgammon does not play sounds

Tags: 12.04, sound, kubuntu

I installed Gnu Backgammon 0.90.0, on Kubuntu 12.04. The graphics work perfectly, but there is no sound, even though enabled in the settings.

Is this a settings or compatibility issue or is it a bug I should file?

How to fix this?

Comment: GnuBG 0.90 on Kubuntu 12.04 sounds perfectly OK here...

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this case was to add a command line for the application to play sound. The command line is added in the settings in the *sound* tab. I added `aplay` as a command. Of course you have to make sure the sound option is enabled too:

[image: settings]

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is of any help, it may be if, like me, you're new to Ubuntu. I'm currently using 12.10. I loaded gnubg and also couldn't get any sound. I tried the solution offered above, with the sound option checked but this didn't work. Today I noticed the sound / speaker icon top right on the main page menu bar wasn't hi-lighted. Brought that up & found it muted by default.
Problem solved ;-)